# Where can you get a Tanooki Suit in Super Mario Brothers 3?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

Where/how can you acquire a Tanooki Suit in *Super Mario Bros. 3*?

The Tanooki Suit gives you the ability to fly (like the leaf/racoon tail) but also gives you the ability to briefly turn into an indestructible statue. It looks a bit like a teddy bear.

Comment: What is the Tanooki Suit? I play the game a lot but don't know the proper names for everything.

Comment: @stephi - its what Mario is wearing after you pick up/use the Item that looks like a leaf. :)

Comment: @stephi: No, the leaf just gives you the racoon tail. The Tanooki Suit looks more like a teddy bear. It gives you the ability to fly (like the leaf/racoon tail) but also gives you the ability to briefly turn into an indestructible statue.

Comment: Tankooni suits are found in toad houses later in the game. This is a link to a video of a tankooni suite (for those who asked what it was, @stephi). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IbMPQtMXnY&sa=X&ei=hbP1UdG8CsGfiQLWm4CoAg&ved=0CAkQqwQ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/nes/525245-super-mario-bros-3/faqs/7459

> WORLD 4
>
> > RED MUSHROOM HOUSE: Vends tanooki
> >     suits!  Get one, they rule!
> >
> > LEVEL 4-5: Later on, you'll see a
> >     brick in the sky.  Bounce off the
> >     bullets  to hit it.  A vine will
> >     spawn.  Do the same thing to get up to
> >     it and  climb it.  You get a tanooki
> >     suit!  Hit the P-Block and follow the
> >     coins to  safety.
>
> WORLD 5
>
> > MUSHROOM HOUSE: Grab a tanooki suit
> >     now!
> >
> > LEVEL 5-5: Whoever thought up this
> >     level should be shot!  Go down the 
> >     second pipe for a tanooki suit, but
> >     careful not to get any leaves or it
> >     goes  to waste.
> >
> > MUSHROOM HOUSE: If you're lucky, you get a tanooki suit.
>
> WORLD 7
>
> > MUSHROOM HOUSE: This one is interesting.  It only vends Tanooki suits, 
> >     hammer suits, and frog suits.  hehe.
> >
> > FORTRESS: The fourth block on the top of that overhang is a P-Block.  You 
> >     can imagine what that does.... ;)     However, it'll create a door which 
> >     has a Tanooki suit ready for you.  DO NOT get the fireflower or you're 
> >     screwed.  Time is of the essence on this level.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the first box in World 5's mushroom house. It works every time.

Comment: That would be because ALL the boxes in that Mushroom House have a Tanooki Suit.

Answer (score 0):

NES--Most--if not all--of the Tanooki/Hammer suits in the first red/brown or blue mushroom houses(depending on which of the houses you see first on the map) in each world are in the first box. Second and additional houses have a different location and maybe the same box every time, too. I don't know if every cartridge is exactly like this or not, but it probably denotes a pattern that allows you to collect a lot of goodies. So, if it is not your first box for you, it's probably the same box in your cartridge. The orange/golden houses appear to be far more random, but Frog suits appear to be really easy to get in most of the houses that have them. It can be like "stealing"; I have gotten to the point that I hate Mushrooms and feel indifferent about Fiery Flowers.

SNES(...All-Stars)--Most--if not all--of the Tanooki/Hammer suits are in the middle box of those same first houses. Again, everything follows the same pattern.

Comment: What makes you think there is a patter in the boxes? I'm asking because I remember hearing somewhere that the item you get is actually decided the moment you step into a mushroom house.

Comment: @DJPirtu IIRC it was based on the time between when you entered the house and when you opened the box, and could be timed precisely enough to reliably get the same thing on every playthrough (just like taking a P-run at the box at the end of each level would get you a star 90% of the time)

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above answers: not all Tanooki Suits are in the Toad Houses on the map. Some are in secret rooms within levels. For example, in 6-3, if you fly to the very top of the level, there is a tall pipe you can enter from the top: this takes you to a room with a block containing the suit.

Answer (score -1):

In World seven, the first house gives leaf/flower/mushroom, the order of these will decide the order of the tanooki/hammer/frog suits in the second and third houses. Cant remember the order but it was 100% for me when I played on original NES. I'd grab chest one, and depending on which of the first three it is, that decides which chest id go to for hammer or tanooki suits.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything that hasn't already been stated in other answers.