# Red Mushroom House in World 4

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

*Super Mario Bros 3*, World 4 has a Red Mushroom House with a rock blocking its path. The Hammer Bros have never left me with an actual hammer, and I never seem to have one when I get to World 4.

Is there a hammer I missed, or is there another way to get to the Red Mushroom House?

Answer (score 13):

There's a hammer located in World 3 (take the canoe and beat the mini-boss on the other side, the mushroom house there is guaranteed to give you one) but there's also a couple places to use it in World 3, if you like. If you hold on to it through World 3 and you'll be able to use it to access that red mushroom house in World 4.

Here's a picture of the world map where the canoe is. The second island with only one house is where you want to be.

[image]

Comment: Judging by [this question's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/where-can-you-get-a-tanooki-suit-in-super-mario-brothers-3), saving a hammer for this house seems to be a good investment.

Comment: You can also get a hammer from one of the Hammer Bros. in World 2. If you're not going for the Warp Whistle, there's nothing much to really use it on there.